# apple vision framework crashes with larger images?

Tags: cocoa, core-image, vision, xcode14, macos-ventura

I've written a script that uses Apple's Vision framework to align two images and save the composite as a new image. Oddly, it works perfectly when the images are small, but when they are larger, it crashes with "**abort trap (6)**", which isn't an error message I'd expect to see, even if there was a built-in limit to the image size. The images aren't even particularly large, only a couple of MB each. [Sample images reproducing the crash](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/vision/vnimagerequesthandler/2880297-perform).

The following is just the relevant code to recreate the crash on macOS 13 Ventura with Xcode 14, which is being caused by the last line: `[handler performRequests:@[request] error:NULL];`

Why would this be happening?

```objectivec
#import <CoreImage/CoreImage.h>
#import <Vision/Vision.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool
    {
        NSString *imagePath1 = @"/path/to/some_image.tif";
        CIImage *image1 = [CIImage imageWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:imagePath1]];
        
        NSString *imagePath2 = @"/path/to/other_image.tif";
        CIImage *image2 = [CIImage imageWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:imagePath2]];
        
        VNImageRequestHandler *handler = [[VNImageRequestHandler alloc] initWithCIImage:image1 options:@{}];
        
        VNHomographicImageRegistrationRequest *request = [[VNHomographicImageRegistrationRequest alloc] initWithTargetedCIImage:image2 options:@{}];
        
        [handler performRequests:@[request] error:NULL];
    }
}
```

Same crash in Swift:

```swift
import CoreImage
import Vision
let imagePath1 = "/path/to/some_image.tif"
let image1 = CIImage(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: imagePath1))!
let imagePath2 = "/path/to/other_image.tif"
let image2 = CIImage(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: imagePath2))!
let handler = VNImageRequestHandler(ciImage: image1)
let request = VNHomographicImageRegistrationRequest(targetedCIImage: image2)
do { try handler.perform([request]) }
catch {}
```

Comment: Arbitrary images for those investigating: [15 MB](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:FullMoon2020.tif) and [160 MB](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:The_Carson_Mansion_is_a_large_Victorian_house_located_in_Old_Town,_Eureka,_California_LCCN2013634803.tif)

Comment: @Cœur Thanks for your comments! The plot thickens: it works fine with both of the arbitrary images you've provided above, however if I take the 160 MB file and crop it in Photoshop to the following dimensions: 4000x5200 and use it for either of the CIImages, then it gives me the "abort trap (6)" message again.

Comment: @Cœur Absolutely. I'm not sure what the preferred way is to reference external images, but hopefully [this link on Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/u0bnjbqs1e3dno7/AAB2s9AVaUtVaA_jwufuTw-Qa?dl=0) is ok? Any of the three images I posted there cause the error message, which I'm more and more convinced is a bug in Apple's framework, since it's so arbitrary in terms of which images don't work. For example, if I rotate these images 90 degrees and re-run the script, it's fine. When I rotate them back, it has the error message again, so it's not anything to do with the format.

Comment: Confirm it's likely an Apple bug in https://developer.apple.com/documentation/vision/vnimagerequesthandler/2880297-perform in Xcode 14E222b:
`/Users/User/Developer/MyPlayground.playground error: Execution was interrupted, reason: signal SIGABRT.
The process has been left at the point where it was interrupted, use "thread return -x" to return to the state before expression evaluation.`

Comment: @Cœur Glad to know it wasn't user-error, and hopefully they fix it in an upcoming release. Thanks very much for your time!

Comment: Not reproducing the crash anymore on macOS 14 Sonoma with Xcode 15 beta. I do not know if an app built with Xcode 15 would crash or not on this code when running on macOS 13 Ventura: up to you to try it maybe.